# Terraform API Gateway v2 Authorizer - Automatically grant API Gateway permission to invoke your Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

In the AWS Console, one has the ability to create an API Gateway Authorizer with a true/false value for "Automatically grant API Gateway [image: permission to invoke your Lambda function":]

However, I don't see this flag exposed via the AWS provider in Terraform for the [aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_authorizer) resource.

Is there a way to set this via Terraform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terraform you need to manually create your IAM statements to make this work. The easiest way is with a resource policy associated with your lambda:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "my_authorizer_lambda_permission" {
    statement_id  = "AllowAPIGatewayInvoke"
    action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = aws_lambda_function.onconnect.function_name
    principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

    source_arn    = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.my_api.execution_arn}/authorizers/${aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer.my_authorizer.id}"
}
```

Comment: This definitely seems to work even though I get this error message when viewing the lambda configuration in the console:

"The API with ID {id} doesn’t include a route with path /* having an integration arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:{account-id}:function:{function-name}"

Do you know if this is a known bug in AWS?

Comment: It looks like an error where it's expecting a REST (v1) api to exist, and giving an error based on that.

Comment: I've tried this as well. Unfortunately, for me it didn't work. There was still nothing configured in "Invoke Permissions" and the request kept responding with _Internal Server Error_

Comment: The same issue for me. I keep getting 500. Unfortunately this method doesn't work with custom authenticators

Comment: This setup works. In order to fix 500 status code - it needs to remove `authorizer_credentials_arn` from API Gateway `aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer` configuration. The error message in AWS Console is a bug from AWS, they are asking you to set API Gateway integration and route for given Lambda, but you actually don't need to do that

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with the `hashicorp/aws@4.8.0` provider. To solve it, I had to create a IAM role and assign the role in the authorizer as [`authorizer_credentials_arn`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_authorizer#authorizer_credentials_arn)

```ruby
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "apig_lambda_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    ]
    effect    = "Allow"
    resources = [aws_lambda_function.authorizer_lambda.arn]
    sid       = "ApiGatewayInvokeLambda"
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "apig_lambda_role_assume" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "sts:AssumeRole",
    ]
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["apigateway.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "apig_lambda_role" {
  name               = "apigateway-authorize-lambda-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.apig_lambda_role_assume.json
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "apig_lambda" {
  name   = "apig-lambda-policy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.apig_lambda_policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "apig_lambda_role_to_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.apig_lambda_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.apig_lambda.arn
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer" "auth" {
  api_id                            = aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.id
  authorizer_type                   = "REQUEST"
  authorizer_uri                    = aws_lambda_function.authorizer_lambda.invoke_arn
  authorizer_credentials_arn        = aws_iam_role.apig_lambda_role.arn
  authorizer_payload_format_version = "2.0"
  authorizer_result_ttl_in_seconds  = 1
  enable_simple_responses           = true
  identity_sources                  = ["$request.header.Authorization"]
  name                              = "lambda-authorizer"
}
```